# PHP - strtok(), associative array relationship

Tags: php, arrays, token, strtok

I'm pretty familiar with the Strtok() function in PHP, and I have had no problem getting the function to work properly for strings in the past. However, I currently have to read a .csv text file (which I've done successfully) where each line is made of 6 fields like so: last name, first name, address, city, district, postal code\r\n    <--carriage return and linefeed at the end

I have to use Strok() to split these by the delimiters and token the words as fields (i.e. last, first, address, etc.). I plan to use an associative array using the last name as the primary key so that I can plug the data into an HTML Table, which is created and working. My issue right now is splitting the file correctly, as it has about 200 lines made of those 6 fields, and storing the strings as fields properly for an array, so the data structure is where I'm having some issues. Here's what I have so far:

```
    $inputFile = fopen("input.csv","r");
    $delimiters = ",";
    $token = strtok($inputFile, $delimiters);
    $n=1;

    while ($token){
      echo "Token $n: $token <br>";
      $token = strtok($delimiters);
      $n++;
    }
```

Obviously, the table is created below it but since I haven't done the data structure quite yet, I don't have the fields for it. I think my token loop may be incorrect for this issue, but I pulled some from an earlier example in my book and an exercise I did where my token process worked but the file structure was different. Thanks for any direction or help on this.

Comment: What's an example line of the CSV and where do you get these "words" to use as the associative array keys?

Comment: Basically each line holds these 6 values and then returns to the next. Here are two examples:

Comment: SELBY,AARON,1519 Santiago de los Caballeros Loop,Mwene-Ditu,East Kasai,22025
GOOCH,ADAM,230 Urawa Drive,Adoni,Andhra Pradesh,2738

Comment: PHP already has built in functions for [parsing csv files](http://php.net/fgetcsv). Why not use those?

Comment: I saw those previously, but this task specifically has to be done with the strtok() function. I'm comfortable with the token function and building an associative array by themselves but I'm hoping for a little bit of guidance on using the two together.

Comment: There are two good ways to do this and tokens are not one of them.

Comment: The Strtok() function was something that we went over earlier in the semester and that's why we're being asked to do it with this function. I definitely agree that there are much better and less cumbersome ways, I'm just trying to find a way that gives the same results using tokens for the sake of my assignment

Comment: You can't parse a CSV file with `strtok`, the grammar is much more complicated than splitting on commas. `"This Is",4,"A ""CSV"" File"` is valid CSV. Normally you need an unruly regular expression, a state machine, or a bit of both.

Comment: @tadman He's not trying to write a general-purpose CSV parser, he's just trying to do a school assignment that uses `strtok()` to split lines at commas.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just saying this could be an impossible assignment if the goal is to parse actual CSV files and not just toy examples.

Comment: @tadman School assignments generally use toy examples.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. This isn't a CSV file so much as one that's coincidentally comma separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are CSV functions in PHP, like [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), so it really is the wrong approach to reinvent the wheel.

Note that in your code you don't actually read the content of the file, as you only get a file pointer.

If you really need to do this with `strtok`, and your CSV is simple, in the sense that it does not have quoted strings, which could have embedded delimiter characters, you could use:

- `file_get_contents()` to read the file content in one string. Of course, `file()` would make it easier for you, as it would already split lines. But I assume that if CSV functions are not allowable for you, then this will neither.
- `strtok` for getting the fields, but at the end of the loop, not at the start, since the initial call with the double arguments already retrieves the first value before the loop.

Code:

```
$input = file_get_contents("input.csv");
$delimiters = ",\n\r";

$token = strtok($input, $delimiters);
$result = [];
$row = [];
while ($token){
    echo "Token $token <br>";
    $row[] = $token;
    if (count($row) == 6) { // write record
        $result[] = $row;
        $row = [];
    }
    $token = str_replace('\r', '', strtok($delimiters));
}

print_r($result);
```

Note that this does not create an associative array. If you need that, then use this code:

```
 $columns = ['last', 'first', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'zip'];
```

and then in your loop, replace `$row[] = $token` by:

```
        $row[$columns[count($row)]] = $token;
```

You can see that version run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/697920). The output for the data you provided in comments is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [last] => SELBY
        [first] => AARON
        [address1] => 1519 Santiago de los Caballeros Loop
        [address2] => Mwene-Ditu
        [address3] => East Kasai
        [zip] => 22025
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [last] => GOOCH
        [first] => ADAM
        [address1] => 230 Urawa Drive
        [address2] => Adoni
        [address3] => Andhra Pradesh
        [zip] => 2738
    )
)
```

Again, this is not advisable. You should use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). That also deals better with strings that could have commas, double quotes or even newlines in them.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely puts me on the right path. I completely understand the issue with it as well, since I've found several seamless ways to do this. For some reason, my professor decided to use a .csv file to show the function of tokens, but that's lost on me. One question: This displays in my table with blank postal fields, yet they show a tokens when I print my results. Could this have to do with the count($row) portion?

Comment: I see no issue like that. I have added a link to the code in my answer, where you can check the content of the *$result* array is correct and contains the zip code. Probably you have another issue in the code that generates the table. You can always introduce a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was going to skip this question because [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), but I was bored:

```
$lines = file($inputFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$delimiters = ",";

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $values = array(strtok($line, $delimiters));
    while($token = strtok($delimiters)){
        $values[] = $token;
    }
    $result[] = $values;
}
```

- Read the file lines into an array
- Loop to get each line and put the first token of the line into a values array
- Loop the line and get all tokens and add to values array
- Add values array to result array

I added an `array_combine()` because you said something about an associative array.  You can use something like this if needed:

```
    $result[] = array_combine(array('last name',
                                    'first name',
                                    'address',
                                    'city',
                                    'district',
                                    'postal code'), $values);
```

If you wanted *last name* to be the key for each result line, which is not advisable as keys are unique and I don't think you can guarantee last names being unique:

```
    $result[$values[0]] = $values;
    //or to remove it from the array but use as the key
    $result[array_unshift($values)] = $values;
```

Comment: That's a lot of work for something that's *still* wrong since `"Spaced Out",2,"This ""Thing"""` is valid CSV depending on your definition of "valid" and "CSV".

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty good for parsing strictly comma-separated values, but not CSV files.

Comment: I have looked at the inherent CSV helpers a lot today, but after attempting that, I was still told to try and use the token function, so it obviously isn't a good way to do it. Since it is only delimited by commas though, it works for this one assignment. Thanks to everyone for the help, though.